# How to get the correct year from NSDate in all circumstances?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I know about `NSDateComponents`, but the thing is that some sort of week-based mechanism will mess up the result when the date is at the head or at the foot of a year.

For example:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSCalendarUnit calendarUnit = NSYearCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:calendarUnit fromDate:self.date];

(lldb) po self.date
2015-12-31 16:00:00 +0000

(lldb) po dateComponents
<NSDateComponents: 0x12f4c83f0>
    Calendar Year: 2016
```

Changing `minimumDaysInFirstWeek` doesn't make much difference either, and `NSDateFormatter` doesn't seem to be a better way.

Comment: What's your time zone. Are you >+8:00?

Comment: @Larme yes (lldb) po [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] timeZone]
Asia/Shanghai (GMT+8) offset 28800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Larme indicated in his comment, your local timezone is affecting your result;

You have specified 4 pm on the 31 Dec 2015 at UTC.  This is midnight on the 1st of January 2016 in your local timezone (UTC+8).

You can use the `NSCalendar` method `componentsInTimeZone` to get the year in a specific time zone:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSTimeZone *tz=[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar componentsInTimeZone:tz fromDate:self.date];
int year=dateComponents.year;  // This will be 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine. The `po` command displays the time description dependent on `UTC` while `NSCalendar` / `NSDateComponents` considers the current time zone.

```
2015-12-31 16:00:00 +0000
```

and

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00 +0800
```

are both the same moment in time.

If you have to deal always with UTC based dates set the time zone of the `NSCalendar` instance to `UTC`.

Answer (score 0):

The "year" component will always return the correct year - based on the calendar that is being used! NSDate is logged in UTC, but the year is calculated using your local timezone. The date you gave was in 2015 in London where the use GMT (close to UTC), but in 2016 in other areas of the world. For example in Australia, where the New Year fireworks have long gone off at that time.

When you were looking at calendar weeks, that's a totally different and completely unrelated subject. 31st of December can be in the last week of one year, or the first week of the next week. But that's not returned by "year". It's returned by "yearForWeekOfYear".